# InAppBrowser not working in Phonegap 3.4.0 for iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm trying to build an app for iOS using phonegap 3.4.0 and jQuery mobile 1.4.0. I've tried everything that everyone's suggested. In the app, I'll click on the link, it opens within the app, but there is no Back button or anything. Therefore I have to force close the app and start again to get back to the main home screen. I have the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://ok-ecig.com','_blank','location=no,closebuttoncaption=Done');" class="ui-btn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i><span> Shop Now</span></a>
```

And in my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id        = "com.[author].[appname]"
version   = "1.0.0">

<name>App Name</name>

<description>
</description>

<author href="http://appauthor.com">
    App Author
</author>

<!--
 Enable individual API permissions here.
 The "device" permission is required for the 'deviceready' event.
 -->
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>

<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />

<!--
 If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
 following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
 permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
 -->
<preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<!-- <preference name="phonegap-version"      value="3.4.0" /> -->      <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
<preference name="orientation"                value="portrait" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="handset" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
 <preference name="DisallowOverscroll"         value="true" />
 <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="false" />
 <preference name="UIWebViewBounce"            value="false" />        <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->

<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="true" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->

<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />

<!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->

<!-- Plugins can also be added here. -->
<!--
 <gap:plugin name="Example" />
 A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins
 -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.2.4" />

<!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />

<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" overwrite="true">
    <false/>
</gap:config-file>

<!--
 Define access to external domains.

 <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
 <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

 Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
 -->
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<access origin="*" />
<!--
 <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
 <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
 <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
 -->
```

My index.html header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.flatui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fa/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script><!-- 3.4.0 -->
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This may help you : http://www.kidsil.net/2014/04/phonegap-inappbrowser-tips/

Comment: thanks. but still not working

Comment: I can see 3 times you included inAppBrowser plugin in config.xml !! Please don't do that .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me tell you how I use it. It may help you find out the problem.

In `config.xml` you should have the following:

```
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "...."
    version   = "....">
```

....

```
<access origin="*" />
```

....

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

....

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"  />
```

In every `.html` file you want to open link with innAppBrowser you should have the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"> 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js></script>
```

NOTE: I think cordova.js should be the very first javascript included in your code. Any other javascripts should follow.


Hope it helps!

Comment: I should've closed this question, as I managed to figure it out a while back, and I did reply to the question below saying that I had done it. Basically when I set up the app through the CLI I used 'phonegap'. When I tried to add the InAppBrowser it didn't work. I started again and in the CLI I used 'cordova' instead. This time it worked and I had no more problems. I believe you use 'phonegap' in the CLI if you are using PhoneGap Build, which I wasn't. I was using plain old Cordova. Thanks for the answer anyway, and as you still submitted an answer after this long I'm going to accept yours! :)

Comment: ahh ok then.. Anyway, since your question is here I hope my answer will help others too! :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the inapp browser plugin is not loading.

By your config it looks like you are using phone gap build to build your project. However it contains a mix of phone gap build and regular phone gap config items.

Since you are using build you should only use:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.2.4" />
```

to add the inapp browser plugin. See https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/658

You should remove this and any other references to the plugin:

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
```

This should enable the plugin to load correctly and you should be able to verify it is included in the build in the phone gap build page.

(If you are not using phonegap build, you need to remove the build related config items and follow the instructions here to install the plugins locally http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface )

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not using phonegap build. I've removed the `<gap:plugin>` line, but still have 3 other references to InAppBrowser: `<feature name="InAppBrowser"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" /></feature>`, `<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>` and `<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser"/>`. Which one is correct?

Comment: Ok, so just to confirm, have you added the plugin using the command line like I mentioned? When you do run the command: `cordova plugin ls` is the inapp browser plugin listed?

Comment: I wrote `cordova plugin ls` and it said the cordova command didn't exist. I've never understood the difference between Phonegap and Cordova as everyone says it's the same. I originally created the app using the phonegap commands in the Terminal, using the Phonegap set up instructions. This time I tried again with the Cordova set up instructions, and had inappbrowser installed in moments and the project working straight away! Cordova's instructions are so much clearer despite the little difference between the two. All sorted now though! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.2.4" />
```

will make sure the inappbrowser plugin your project.

**Make sure the cordova.js at the very first javascript included of your index.html.**

This is works well for my project.